# Traefic docker container reverse-proxy redirect fails to ports provided by other containers: Gateway timeout

Tags: docker, traefik

Setup: I have a variety of native applications and docker applications on a nas device.
(simplistic example).

```
host
: 8080 (console)
: 81 (apache)
: <port> and more (individual nas applications)
- container:traefik
  :80
- container:nginx
  :90
- container:customcode
  :4000
- and more (individual applications)
  :<port>
```

(host is 192.168.1.22).

**All containers and applications work and are reachable via '`http://192.168.1.22:<port>`'

I was attempting to use traefik with simplistic names to manage the ports.
i.e.

- 'apache' redirect to http://192.168.1.22:81 (host exposed) - works
- 'nas' redirect to http://192.168.1.22:8080 (host exposed) - works
- 'nginx' redirect to http://192.168.1.22:90 (container exposed) -
  fails

The traefik setup is able to redirect to all ports on the host itself, but none of the ports exposed by docker. This works for sites on different hosts as well. for ports exposed by containers I get a 'Gateway timeout' error

(only Log file entry: `"'504 Gateway Timeout' caused by: dial tcp 192.168.1.22:90: i/o timeout"`).

I cannot use labels on the containers as they don't (and some cannot) share networks. I just want traefik to route to the IP:Port without worrying about if the port is provided by a container or not.

traefik.toml

```
loglevel = "ERROR"

[Log]
  filePath = "/etc/traefik/traefik.log"
  level = "DEBUG"  

[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"

[api]
  dashboard = true

[providers.docker]
  watch = false
  exposedByDefault = false
  endpoint = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"  
  
[providers.file]
  watch = true
  filename = "/etc/traefik/services.toml"
```

services.toml

```
[http]
  [http.services]
    [http.services.nas]
      [http.services.nas.loadBalancer]
        [[http.services.nas.loadBalancer.servers]]
          url = "http://192.168.1.22:8080/"
    [http.services.test90]
      [http.services.test90.loadBalancer]
        [[http.services.test90.loadBalancer.servers]]
          url = "http://192.168.1.22:90/" #this does not work#
    [http.services.test81]
      [http.services.test81.loadBalancer]
        [[http.services.test81.loadBalancer.servers]]
          url = "http://192.168.1.22:81/"
```

docker compose:

```
version: "3.5"
services:
  traefik:
    image: "traefik:2.4"
    container_name: "traefik"
    restart: always
    environment:
      - PUID=<id>
      - PGID=<id>
    ports:
      - "443:443"
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - "/shr/traefik/:/etc/traefik/"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.rule=Host(`traefik`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.service=api@internal"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.entrypoints=http,https"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.middlewares=auth"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.auth.basicauth.users=admin:<pass>"

      - "traefik.http.routers.nas.entrypoints=http"
      - "traefik.http.routers.nas.rule=Host(`nas`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.nas.service=nas@file"

      - "traefik.http.routers.test81.entrypoints=http"
      - "traefik.http.routers.test81.rule=Host(`apache`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.test81.service=test81@file"

      - "traefik.http.routers.test90.entrypoints=http"
      - "traefik.http.routers.test90.rule=Host(`nginx`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.test90.service=test90@file"
    networks:
      - proxy

  whoami:
    image: "traefik/whoami"
    container_name: "whoami"
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.whoami.rule=Host(`whoami`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.whoami.entrypoints=http"

    networks:
      - proxy

networks:
  proxy:
    external:
      name: proxy
```

Comment: So in my case, a container that had multiple networks assigned caused this problem *sometimes*. By specifying the traefik network, this issue solved itself for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to assing the correct traefik network in the application that causes the problem:

In the docker-compose.yml:

```yaml
labels:
[...]
 - "traefik.enable=true"
 - "traefik.docker.network=foobar"
[...]
```

Where "foobar" is the docker network that traefik is also in. Ideally, an external docker network.

Comment: I will try this next time I have an issue. My setup is fairly stable now so I haven't bothered to re-investigate.

Answer (score 0):

As the selected answer is correct for the current question, I have run with the same situation where I get `traefik msg="'504 Gateway Timeout' caused by: dial` but the reason was completely different:

Ensure that all docker containers are **on the same timezone**.  I have created a traefik container without specifying the timezone, but in others I have it (fore logging purposes). On the traefik's dashboard all services are shown, but the redirects returns a gateway timeout. Putting all services on the same timezone has fixed it for me.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that adding network_mode: "host" to the docker-compose and removing the custom network fixed the issue.

Comment: This isn't a solution, this is changing the entire design. See my comment for what solved the issue for me.